# jQuery mouseenter event firing uncontrollably

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone has run into this before, or can tell me what's wrong with my code.

I have a button that on mouseenter, widens and changes the text. On mouseleave, it reverts back to its orignal state.

[I set up a jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rurabe/Esvag/1/) This is the relevant code (abbreviated):

```
var labelChanger = function (off, on) {
  $el.off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
  $el.mouseenter(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      changeContent(on);
      $(this).animate({'width': '70%'}, 50);
  }).mouseleave(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      changeContent(off);
      $(this).animate({'width': '50%'}, 50);
  });
};
```

It works okay, but there is a weird thing happening where if the mouse enters the box from the top or bottom, it can get into a state where any movement of the mouse triggers a mouseenter event (this happens approximately 25% of the time.) You can see it firing by the element 'flickering' and I added a log of sorts underneath it.

But if the mouse enters from the side, it is stable and will act as expected.

Does anyone know why this is??? I'm stumped.

Comment: Why not change it to use mouseover and mouseout?

Comment: Looks to me like it needs to have some sort of spinning lock.

Comment: Have a look at adding stop() to your animation code blocks - http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: On my computer it seems to be working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `off()`, you should also be using `on()`, and the problem with the mouseenter is that the event bubbles, and when inserting new content, the mouseenter on that new content bubbles up, triggering a new event etc. Try something like :

```
var labelChanger = function (off, on) {
    $el.off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
    $el.on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            if (e.target == this) {
                changeContent(on);
                $(this).animate({'width': '70%'}, 50);
            }
        },
        mouseleave(function (e) {
            changeContent(off);
            $(this).animate({'width': '50%'}, 50);
        }
    });
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Esvag/3/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I figured it had something to do with bubbling, but I thought I had taken care of that with .stopPropagation(). I didn't think of using the event object to check.

Comment: If let's say, we want to do it the opposite way. Default width is 70% and if we trigger mouseenter it should shrink to 50%. In that case it will flicker when mouse enters from sideways i.e. from left & right. As happening in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sucvpa9L/). How can we solve it then?

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the contents of the span, the change in size (caused by the change in text length) is causing the mouse to "leave" and "re-enter" the span rapidly. The mouse entry/exit event is bubbling up from the span to the wrapper, triggering the script to change it again and starting the chain all over.